# Ember js behavior error

Tags: javascript, ember.js

routes/map.js

```
 model() {
     return this.store.findAll('entity');

  },
  setupController(controller, model) {
    var self = this;
    controller.set('lat', 39.000000000000000);
    controller.set('lng', 25.000000000000000);
    controller.set('zoom', 3);
  },
```

this my template

```
    <div class="menu-btn ">&#9776;</div>
<nav class="pushy  pushy-left">
  <div class="profile">
    <div class="avatar"><img src="{{rootURL}}/assets/img/avatar/ava_16.jpg" alt="#"><span>5</span></div>
    <h3><a href="03.html">Ananew Matvey</a></h3>
  </div>
  <ul class="side_menu">
    <li><a href="index.html"><i class="fa fa-bookmark-o"></i>Promo page</a></li>
    <li><a href="01.html" class="animsition-link"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>Map</a></li>
    <li><a href="05.html"><i class="fa fa-list"></i>Place list</a></li>
    <li><a href="04.html"><i class="fa fa-th"></i>Place grid</a></li>
    <li><a href="02.html"><i class="fa fa-building-o"></i>Place</a></li>
    <li><a href="03.html"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>User profile</a></li>
    <li><a href="06.html"><i class="fa fa-book"></i>Blog</a></li>
    <li><a href="07.html"><i class="fa fa-file-powerpoint-o"></i>Open post</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

when i remove the model hook 
the navbar work good but if i use hook model function it doesn't do any thing

Comment: You are not setting the model in `setupController` because you're not calling super, is that on purpose? Means the model hook isn't doing anything.

Comment: no i just forget to write those line in my question  this._super(controller,model);     controller.set('entities', model);